# Dompdf Fails to Display Image

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

This code transforms HTML into a PDF.
When generating the PDF, the image doesn't appear and displays an error stating 'image not found or type unknown'. How can I resolve this? I've implemented this code within a WordPress plugin.Could you provide a solution? I've tried numerous approaches, but nothing seems to work.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
ob_start();
include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'doc.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$outputPath = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'order_' . $order_id . '_suffix.pdf';
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($outputPath, $output);
```

In the doc.php file, I've included the following:

```
<img src="/home/u549586825/domains/asteamwork.com/public_html/vac/wp-content/plugins/custom_checkout_popup/logo.png">
```

When generating the PDF, the image doesn't appear and displays an error stating 'image not found or type unknown'. How can I resolve this? I've implemented this code within a WordPress plugin.

Could you provide a solution? I've tried numerous approaches, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You could try `https://domain.ext/home/....`, using your domain and extension, instead of starting at `/home/....`. Remember you load a HTML string, it doesn't know the domain and extension. Alternatively you could try to [base64 encode the image](https://www.base64-image.de/), that always works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Set Attribute `$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled',TRUE);`

Example:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled',TRUE);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();`
```